# Is there a way to build asset bundle that exclude texture2d from an image?

Tags: unity-game-engine

In unity 4.x, I can archive this because I can select my resource type directly as Sprite variable before putting it into the bundle via BuildAssetBundle. However, in Unity 5.x, I need to put the name in the Editor can I cannot choose my resource type as Sprite only in the Editor. When I make the bundle, bundle will have both Texture2D and Sprite which I only want Sprite to save the memory and disk space. The bundle will exclude Texture2D only if I create the bundle from Prefab not the image itself but I want only the raw image. What should I do?

Comment: could you upload an asset bundle with just the sprite from unity 4, please?

Comment: The solution is here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/91989/is-there-a-way-to-exclude-original-sprites-in-spritepacker-thats-in-asset-bundl

Comment: Could you make it work? The Unity API page marks CompleteAssets as obsolete in 5.0.

Comment: That's why I asked this question here. :) Actually, it said obsolete but it's still working in 5.0 but it's not sure for the future since it's obsolete of course. 
See http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BuildingAssetBundles.html for more information. It's still working in 5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been fixed by Unity in Patch 5.1.2p1. You don't need to do anything fancy at all. Unity will do it all for you. Just follow the simple build asset bundle step and that's it. :)

Answer (score 3):

As clarification for future readers, I'm taking into account [your other question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/91989/is-there-a-way-to-exclude-original-sprites-in-spritepacker-thats-in-asset-bundl), and that the reason you want to exclude the original texture is because you use the atlas that the Sprite Packer generates.

**Short answer:** Just don't add the textures in any bundle and let everything be taken care of in the shadows. For each bundle, any sprite or atlas needed will be referenced by the object that needs it, so they will be included.

**Long, but insightful answer:** First, let's compare the two AssetBundle buidling pipelines:

- In Unity 4.X, to create an AssetBundle you chose the assets you wanted to bundle together. You would then call [BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundle](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundle.html), using the [BuildAssetBundleOptions](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/BuildAssetBundleOptions.html) to optionally [CollectDependencies](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/BuildAssetBundleOptions.CollectDependencies.html) or include the [CompleteAssets](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/BuildAssetBundleOptions.CompleteAssets.html).
- In Unity 5.X, the old system is flagged as obsolete but still supported, though [according to this post](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/new-assetbundle-build-system-in-unity-5-0.293975/page-2#post-1957724) it might not be in the future. Adding to that, the new system will be further developed, so using the old one should be avoided.
- The new pipeline is now integrated into the [AssetImporter](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetImporter-assetBundleName.html). Now, when building a bundle, the behaviour is that of having both CollectDependencies and CompleteAssets enabled in the old method.

Sprites are generated by the texture's import settings, and don't have any `AssetImporter` of their own. The texture atlases created by the Sprite Packer are [cached in \Library\AtlasCache](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpritePacker.html), so they don't have `AssetImporters` either.
This means that individual sprites and packed atlases can only be included in a bundle when they are dependencies of another included asset. [As said by someone working on it.](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/new-assetbundle-build-system-in-unity-5-0.293975/#post-1939649)

If you add a texture to a pack, all the sprites it created will be added (this is the CompleteAssets behaviour), but of course this will add the texture itself too.
If a sprite is added, the texture it uses will be added too (CollectDependencies behaviour), regardless of if it's a texture file in the project or a Sprite Packer atlas.

The bottom line is that you don't want to add the texture. At all. Never. The original textures are for editor work only. Instead, you need to do add to the bundle anything **else** that references the sprites, but not the texture itself.

The *hackiest* way to do that is using a prefab with a script like this:

```
public class SpriteReferences : UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour {

    public UnityEngine.Sprite[] sprites;
}
```

But chances are that among all the things you want to add to the bundle (prefabs, scenes, scriptableObjects) the sprites you need are already referenced, so they will be added, and in turn any needed atlas will be added too. And everything done without adding the original texture.

**Beware:** If a single object in an asset bundle references a sprite, its whole atlas will be added. Keep your packing tags organized, they should roughly correspond to the bundles you make.

Comment: Not really answer my question straight but it's still a very useful information. Thank you!

Comment: Would be better if there's a way to add sprite into the inspector automatically since I have lots of sprite and could not be able to add all sprites by hand.

Comment: @PaiboonPanusbordee aren't the sprites referenced by anything else?